# Blueimp fileupload() callbacks not called

Tags: file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using Blueimp fileupload() to post image files to a django-tastypie API.

The code below works correctly as far as the file is being uploaded:

```
        $("#image").fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            start: function() {
                console.log("start fileupload");
            },
            progress: function(e, data) {
                console.log(data.loaded + " " + data.total);
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
            },
            done: function(e, data) {
                console.log("done uploading file.");
            }                   
        });

        $("#image").bind('fileuploadfinished', function (e, data) {
            console.log("fileuploadfinished");
        });
```

However, the `done` callback is never called. I tried binding the `fileuploadfinished` and that is also never called.

`start` and `progress` are both called as expected.

`beforeSend` is undocumented, but is needed by django-tastypie for `SessionAuthentication` - removing it doesn't change that `done` and `fileuploadfinished` is never called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, django-tastypie correctly returns a 201 status code. However, this status code is not considered a success by fileupload.

This code handles the status code manually:

```
    $("#image").fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $.cookie('csrftoken'));
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 201) {
                    console.log("Created");
                }
            } else {
                console.log("NoGood");
            }
        },
    });
```

That means, the `complete` callback is called whether success or failure, and checking the `readyState` and `status` together can tell whether it succeeded.

There are some other ways to get this to work, however I think this is the best. More details here:

[Data inserted successful but jquery still returning error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233553/data-inserted-successful-but-jquery-still-returning-error)

Comment: life saver! its been literally 2 days stuck on the callbacks that do not fire back. complete did it for me

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. it is because you set your **datatype 'json'.**
Just leave this out or put it to plain and it will work.
Your server , or uploadhandler isn't return a json answer.

Comment: actually a good hint but wrong so far as it should be json. It is not because the upload handler triggers a notice as html