# jQuery Ajax returns "parsererror" despite JSON is valid and return code is 201

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm sending a query to a server and awaiting a JSON object in return:

```
var a = $.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    data: post_data,
    timeout: 5000,
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr)
    {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    }
})
.success (function (data, status, jqxhr)
{       
    onSuccess();
})
.error (function(x, status, jqxhr) 
{   
    onError_(x);
});
```

That works perfectly, I'm getting the expected JSON in return:

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":201,"statusText":"Created"}
```

But not `onSuccess()` but `onError_()` gets called and `status` is set to `'parsererror'` despite the return is a valid JSON (I've tested it with various tools like [this](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b5a6b069afd812d6c7e52066cd51aa56)) and even the status of the JSON element is `201` which according to [this](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) page represents a positive status code:

> **10.2.2 201 Created**
>
> The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created [...]

Is it possible, that jQuery's Ajax interprets the 201 status as a failure?

**Update:**

Also adding `dataType: "json",` to my request doesnt change the situation. The jQuery documentation for `.ajax()` says

> **dataType** (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))

So when I implemented it I thought jQuery wouldn't be so dumb to cause errors because it doesn't recognize JSON and it seems that I was right because the error  remains the same.

**Update:**

The common fix for this problem seems to be, adding `dataType: "json"` to the ajax call, however this didn't work for me, so I did an ugly but working workaround:

```
.error (function(x, status, jqxhr) 
{
    if (x.status == 201) /* jQuery thinks, Status 201 means error, but it doesnt so we have to work around it here */
    {
        // handle success
        return;
    }

    // handle errors
}
```

Anyway, I'd be still interested in a proper fix

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data inserted successful but jquery still returning error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233553/data-inserted-successful-but-jquery-still-returning-error)

Comment: Two possible causes for your behaviour, 1) the server returns a different status code for the HTTP response (not the one specified inside the JSON data, but the one in the HTTP status line. 2) you don't specify a dataType in your ajax request and the server does not set the correct MIME type for the response.

Comment: The `dataType: "json"` doesn't fix the problem, I updated my question

Comment: Probably you did already, but did you doublecheck that the server really returns what you are expecting?

Comment: Yes, because 1. everything works fine with the workaround and 2. the server hosts a telecommunication system of a very big company so I dont think that they release a version which isn't working if you have to pay thousands of euros for it. Anyway, it works so the return is correct

Comment: Do you have a way of dumping the whole response (including headers)? Or alternatively try adding a header like "Accept: application/json" to your request...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful: ResponseText is equal to "" and that is not a valid json. It should be null or "{}"

Comment: is absolutely right, the server is NOT returning JSON. So you should change your dataType to text.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I was just confused because the return itself is JSON but I never mentioned `responseText`. Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, write 
 dataType: "json" 
in ajax call.

Comment: The `dataType: "json"` doesn't fix the problem, I updated my question