# Ajax success callback call error function always

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this function getResult()

```
<script>
function getResult()
{
dataString = "un="+user+"&pw="+password+"&cid="+cid;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://myexamplesite.com",
    data: dataString,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

when i call the function, i am getting the value in background what i want, means this gives me success output but this function always call error function on success call back
I am not sure and even not found what is wrong with this script.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what `dataType` are you returning from request?are you returning that type?

Comment: async: false add this and try again then you can see what is giving error

Comment: Hello Pekka, I am using dataType: "jsonp" in this function

Comment: There's not much wrong with the script, the problem is that it doesnt recognize the return ob your server as a successful return. If the server returns a JSON, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350478/jquery-ajax-returns-parsererror-despite-json-is-valid-and-return-code-is-201

Comment: The return is a valid JSON but `returnText` ist empty in this case and nothing is not a valid JSON

Comment: Mehmet Eren Yener : its returning "` Reference Error: Successfull is not defined"

Comment: Hello Tom Doodler: there is returnText is not empty, its "Successful"

Comment: hello guys, I am running this from cross domain, is there any problem related this here in my case ?

Comment: Yes.. add one most important thing dataType:"jsonp" after crossDomain: true,

Comment: still the result is same as before